# Jquery Mask Strange Behavior In Android Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, android-browser, jquery-mask

i have an input with type `text` in my html file and want to mask it with `00/00` pattern . but when i want to type it sample input 12/10 it converts to 12/01. if i explicitly type `/` character everything works fine. i test my html code in all desktop browsers and everything works.

### html

```
<div class="cardInfo">
    <label>Card Exp Date</label>
    <label>
        <input type="text" id="expData" class="expDataInput" name="expData"/>
    </label>
</div>
```

### js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var expData = $('#expData');
    expData.mask("00/00", {placeholder: "__/__"});

});
```

here is [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6xcek46f/) Link